# Saving battery on laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, battery

I have searched google for an answer but I didn't find a good one. I just bought a laptop (MSI GE62 2QD) and installed ubuntu. My problem is that the battery runs out very fast. Is there some way to switch to a power-saving mode when for example browsing the web and then switch to performance mode when playing a game?

I read somewere that the graphics card draws a lot of power and the drivers on Linux aren't able to automatically disable it when not needed like in Windows. I am using the proprietary Nvida driver from the additional drivers list.

I have tried opening NVIDIA X Server Settings and under PRIME Profiles select Intel (Power Saving Mode). This didn't seem to help much and it's very anoying having to reboot the computer each time I change these settings (just logging out didn't seem to be enough).

My question is, how can I save battery on my laptop when I do not need full performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shut off your nvidia card using PRIME and install TLP and you will have good savings. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/tlp

Comment: How does it work? Can I switch between power-saving and performance profiles? Or does it automatically detect what is needed?

Comment: Everything including kernel tuning for powersaving is done automatically, check the website.

Comment: TLP is now available under official packages - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/tlp

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing bumblebee? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee
after installation you can run a program with a discreet graphics card with "primusrun" at the beginning of the command, but just with usual stuff without the command the whole laptop will just run on the intel graphics. (this worked with my msi gs60) have a look here for running steam games and more info https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437

Comment: I saw something about bumbelbee before and it looks nice. Your link says the command is optirun. Is it optirun or primusrun?

Comment: Bumblebee doesn't work. When I install it I try to reboot, but I get no splash screen and it says something about `Starting Light Display Manager` and hangs.

Comment: I followed [this tutorial](http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.se/2015/10/how-to-install-bumblebee-and-latest.html) and now it works